# Javascript to get latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to incorporate the user's current longitude and latitude into an iframe url. My code is below.

```
<script>

var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon = position.coords.longitude;

document.write('<iframe src=http://weather.wdtinc.com/imap/imap5/?&INIT_LAT='+lat+'&INIT_LON='+lon+'> </iframe>');
</script>
```

This just gives me a blank page. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i don;t understand why people would rather ask on here and wait god knows how long for an answer than just google it.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`...ever. Instead, hard code the iFrame into the `body` of the page and give it an `id`. Then access the iFrame via the DOM and inject what you want into it.  More importantly, your page would trying to access another domain's content via that iFrame and that is, most likely, violating the "Same Origin Policy" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)  that is baked into all modern browsers.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Geolocation is only allowed on secure sites (`https://`) by Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You missed  quote in src

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      document.write('<iframe src="http://weather.wdtinc.com/imap/imap5/?&INIT_LAT=' +
        position.coords.latitude+
        '&INIT_LON='+
        position.coords.longitude+'" > </iframe>');
  });
```